# MySQL CASE SELECT using Ruby

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby, select, case

I am attempting to recreate a CASE SELECT I successfully achieved in Sequel Pro; all of which utilizes MySQL.

The following is my SQL query:

```
SELECT company_db.location.id AS "Id",
    company_db.location.name AS "Name",
    CASE WHEN company_db.location.id = 8 THEN "NY"
        WHEN company_db.location.id = 37 THEN "ATL"
        ELSE NULL END AS "Location Code"
    FROM company_db.location
    WHERE (company_db.location.id = 8 OR company_db.location.id = 37);
```

The following is my entire Query.rb file:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require "mysql"

mysql = Mysql.init()
mysql = Mysql.new("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "company_db")

results = mysql.query("SELECT company_db.location.id,
    company_db.location.name,
    CASE WHEN company_db.location.id = 8 THEN "NY"
        WHEN company_db.location.id = 37 THEN "ATL"
        ELSE NULL END
    FROM company_db.location
    WHERE (company_db.location.id = 8 OR company_db.location.id = 37);")
results.each {|row|; print row;}
```

And finally, the following is the error I receive in the command prompt:

```
le-iMac:Workspace jerry$ ruby Query.rb
Query.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'
CASE WHEN company_db.location.id = 8 THEN "NY"
                                             ^
caseSel.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
        WHEN company_db.location.id = 37 THEN "ATL"
                                                  ^
```

When I remove that `CASE` statement and just `SELECT` from `company_db` it works perfectly.

What is the correct syntax for the `CASE SELECT` I am trying to accomplish here?

Comment: You should really consider using something like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) to access your database rather than interfacing with the low-level driver directly. The driver provides a very minimal amount of support, leaving a lot of work up to you. The purpose of the driver is to make writing things like ActiveRecord and Sequel possible.

Comment: Also worth noting, this should be `mysql = Mysql.connect(...)` as per the documentation. There's no need to call `Mysql.init`.

Comment: Thank you for the tips and syntax help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this `"NY"` in your query with `'NY'` and the same for `"ATL"`, when you use `"` you end your sql query string.

Comment: I get this error: `le-iMac:Workspace jerry$ ruby Query.rb
caseSel.rb:12:in 'query': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near CASE WHEN company_db.location.id = 8 THEN 'NY' (Mysql::Error)
  WHEN company_db' at line 3
 from Query.rb:12:in '<main>'`

Comment: No you're right I ironed out all the kinks and it works!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use double quotes in a double-quoted string you have a few options:

```
s = "this has \"literal\" quotes"
s = 'this uses "single" quotes'
s = %Q[this can use any kind of quotes, but not "brackets"]

s = <<END
this has "quotes" and can go
on for "multiple lines"
END
```

When using a database you want to avoid manually quoting strings whenever possible:

```
# Define a statement with placeholders where the data should be
stmt = mysql.prepare(%Q[
  CASE WHEN company_db.location.id = ? THEN ?
    WHEN company_db.location.id = ? THEN ?
    ELSE NULL END
])

# Provide the data used for this query
stmt.execute(8, 'NY', 37, 'ATL')
```